# What's a safe, easily executable experiment to confirm that quantization of light occurs directly to the retina?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, optics, photons, vision

What's a safe, easily executable experiment to confirm that quantization of light occurs directly to the retina.

We know that light is quantized when projected on to a surface, or on to an inanimate detector, then the surface or the detector observed.

An eye can detect a single photon. This means we should be able to quantize light such that a single photon lands on the retina of the left eye or of the right, and the observer confirm it is seen in only one eye.

What's a design for this experiment?

Comment: Following up on that, this site is not to get a bunch of minions to do your work for you. If you just tell people to do things your question will be closed immediately.

Comment: In quantum field theory, light is quantized regardless of whether it is projected onto a surface or onto an inanimate detector. The electromagnetic field is a quantum field, and photons are its quanta. We do not quantize light. All light is quantized as part of its essential nature. There is no *un*-quantized light.

Comment: @Ghoster what's the experiment?

Comment: @Ghoster Re your "in quantum field theory..." comment.  As every good scientist knows, theory gives way to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and I am not a biologist), a retinal cell can respond to a single photon, but the back end circuits need 5-9 photons to arrive within 100 ms to trigger a neural response.

Nevertheless, here's the experiment: use spontaneous parameter down conversion to generate correlated photon pairs. Send one stream to a sensitive detector, the other to a "subject". Go from there.

Last time I detected single photons, the quantum efficiency of the detector was around 20 percent, which could present a problem. Nevertheless, the statistics can be worked out. Maybe there's an experiment there.

Comment: What's the purpose of generating the correlated pairs?  Is it so that one can measure independently of the person, when a photon is emitted?

Comment: so you know the input to the eyeball.